When does $K(\gamma)=K(\delta)$ or $K(\gamma, \delta)=K(\gamma+\delta)$ hold?
Let $K$ be a finite extension of $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $\alpha, \beta$ be algebraic elements over $K$ and $\gamma, \delta$ be algebraic elements over $K(\alpha,\beta)$ such that

$K \subset K(\alpha, \beta) \subset K(\gamma, \delta)$, all Galois extensions

$K(\alpha)=K(\beta)$

if helpful, then I should say that $\alpha \neq \beta$ and $\alpha=p^{\frac{r}{n}},~\beta=p^{\frac{s}{n}}$ for some positive integers $r \neq s$ and $n$.


and the elements $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $\beta$ are dependent by the relations
\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma^{p^2}+p \delta&=\alpha ~~\longrightarrow (i)\\
\delta^{p^3}+p \gamma&=\beta ~~ \longrightarrow (ii)
\end{eqnarray}

I would like to show $K(\gamma)=K(\delta)$.


Is the above information enough?


Or do we need more assumptions?


Once we show the equality $K(\gamma, \delta)=K(\gamma+\delta)$, then I think $K(\gamma)=K(\delta)$ will follow. For, the given assumption, $K(\alpha)=K(\beta)$ implies
\begin{align}
K(\gamma^{p^2}+p \delta)&=K(\delta^{p^3}+p \gamma) \\
\Rightarrow K(\gamma^{p^2},p \delta)&=K(\delta^{p^3},p \gamma) ~~\longrightarrow (iii) \\
& (\text{assuming}~K(\gamma+\delta)=K(\gamma, \delta)) 
\end{align}
Now from equation $(i)$, we have
\begin{align}
p \delta&=\alpha-\gamma^{p^2} \\
\Rightarrow K(p \delta)&=K(\alpha-\gamma^{p^2}) \supset K(\gamma^{p^2})  \\
\Rightarrow K(p \delta)&\supset K(\gamma^{p^2}) \\
\Rightarrow K(p \delta)&=K(p \delta, \gamma^{p^2})~~\longrightarrow (iv) 
\end{align}
Similarly, from equation $(ii)$, we have
\begin{align}
p \gamma&=\beta-\delta^{p^2} \\
\Rightarrow K(p \gamma)&=K(\beta-\delta^{p^2}) \supset K(\delta^{p^3}) \\
\Rightarrow K(p \gamma)&\supset K(\delta^{p^3}) \\
\Rightarrow K(p \gamma)&=K(p \gamma,\delta^{p^3})~~\longrightarrow (v) 
\end{align}
Using $(iv)$ and $(v)$ in equation $(iii)$, we get
$K(p \gamma)=K(p \delta)$ which implies $k(\gamma)=K(\delta)$.
Therefore, the question reduces to showing $K(\alpha, \delta)=K(\gamma+\delta)$. Someone might think of another method than the above, which might not even require $K(\gamma, \delta)=K(\gamma+\delta)$.
Anyway, I am not sure how to show $K(\gamma, \delta)=K(\gamma+\delta)$, as it doesn't hold in general. But I hope that in our case it will hold, especially since the given condition $K(\alpha)=K(\beta)$ might play a role here. If we apply Van der Waerden's primitive element theorem to $K(\alpha,\beta)$, then there exist non-zero scalars $k,l \in K$ such that $$k(\alpha,\beta)=K(\alpha+k \beta)=K(\alpha+l \beta)$$
where the scalars $k,l$ can be chosen $1$, since $K(\alpha)=K(\beta)$ implies $k(\alpha)=K(\alpha,\beta)=K(\beta)=K(\alpha+\beta)$.
I think we need to use the same strategy for $k(\gamma, \delta)$.
I hope for some ideas.
Note: With the advice of professor Lubin, I have changed the notations. The below comments are still valid with the understanding that $a \to \alpha,~ b \to \beta,~ \alpha \to \gamma, ~\beta \to \delta$.

If $K(a)=K(b)$ then $K(a,b)=K(a)=K(b),$ and there is not reason to have two variables $a,b.$ Are you sure that is your requirement, or is it just $K(a)\cong K(b)?$

@ThomasAndrews, I have four algebraic elements $a,b, \alpha, \beta$ giving the field extensions. I have given that $K(a)=K(b)$, I want to show $K(\alpha)=K(\beta)$ based on the given assumptions.

So, as @Thomas says, $b$ is superfluous.

@GerryMyerson, $b$ may be superfluous, but both $a,b$ are different elements with different $p$-adic valuation (denominator is same but numerator of the valuations are different). I have given the last two equations of my questions, this is where $b$ appears. Anyway, I am unable to show $K(\alpha, \beta)=K(\alpha+\beta)$, which is required to prove $K(\alpha)=K(\beta)$, in the above method

It doesn't say anywhere that $a\ne b$, much less that they have different $p$-adic valuations. What you have is an algebraic extension $E$ of $K$, with $\alpha^{p^2}+p\beta$ and $\beta^{p^2}+p\alpha$ both in $E$.

@Garrison, sorry but yes, I didn't mention $a \neq b$ anywhere, as I felt it is not required. I have the assumption $K(a)=K(b)$, this says that $a,b$ can be different or equal. But, in my original problem, $a$ and $b$ are different elements of the form $a=p^{m/n}$ and $b=p^{r/n}$.

@GerryMyerson, Am I doing correct in equation (4) above? I mean if equation $(4)$ follows from the previous line

It didn't say, and doesn't say, anywhere, that $a=p^{m/n}$ and $b=p^{r/n}$. Maybe you should edit all this new information that you have been withholding from us into the body of your question. And who is Garrison?

@GerryMyerson, I think I have edited my question already before your last comment. If you check the the finishing part of my question, I have written within a bracket

Please have pity on an aged mathematician with failing eyesight and avoid using “$a$” and “$\alpha$” in the same sentence.

@Lubin, I apologise for the bad notations, Professor Lubin. I have implemented your advice. Please see the revised question. I also apologise to the previous people who made comments based on $a, b, \alpha, \beta$, because I changed the notations.
